# Why using (.*) in htaccess does not give result as expected?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get all characters that is not a "/"..However, it returns me withn an error  all the time ..The url I am accessing is `http://localhost/framework/help/jh/ghjghj`.. I intend to use (.*) to achieve this and store all characters help/jh/ghjghj

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1
```

However in my index.php file when i print $_REQUEST['t'], it returns me with

```
array(1) { ["t"]=> string(9) "index.php" }
```

Why it doesnot store the help/jh/ghjghj in var t?

Comment: Where is `y` in `$_REQUEST['y']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
```